# Firebase doesn't send notification after generating new token

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase for receiving push notification. I am getting FCM token on the first install. On log out of the app, I am deleting FCM token and generating a new one on the next login.

Everything works fine, firebase provides me a new token. but still, I can't receive notification from firebase.

Following is the code I am using.

Delete Token

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
```

Generate new token

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                                token=instanceIdResult.getToken();
                            }
                        });
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service
            android:name="FirebaseMessaging.EDOFirebaseService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>

     </service>
```

Please help me to find out, what is an issue. I am following all the steps described in firebase documentation.

Comment: Please share the msg body, that you are sending from firebase.

Comment: `I can't receive notification from firebase` From Firebase console? From your server? Did you send the new token to your server? Do you handle FCM when your app is in the foreground?

Comment: from server. yes i have sent the new token to  my server. andd yes, i have handled FCM for foreground, and i have tested an app with debugging breakpoints, the onMessageReceived is not getting invoked. @EugenPechanec

Comment: @MayuriKhinvasara i am sending message from server

Comment: Refer this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58587480/1300813) for right format of server side message.

Comment: i am getting the message sent from server in app , on first token generation, but when i delete the existing token, and generate new one, i am not getting any notification. @MayuriKhinvasara

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#deleteInstanceId()) states that 'deleteInstanceId' is a blocking function and should not be called it on the main thread.
You can call it on a background thread and after completion , generate a new token.

```
public void logoutFromFCM() {

        // Disable auto initilization
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(false);

        //Delete instance
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {

                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
                 //TODO Generate new token after this

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Also you can set the right status for auto init

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(false);
```

You can also set it via manifest file

```
  <meta-data android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
             android:value="false" />
```

Also make sure, 
(1) you are sending the msg body in right format (data or notification type) and handling the right foreground/background state.
(2) You are sending to the right tokens.
(3) Sent the msg in right format (data or notification payload) from server. Receive it in proper format from android client. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58587480/1300813) answer

Also, as a matter of practice there is no need to delete the token for logout. Just unsubscribe or disable on logout. And you can reassign the token to the new or old user on next login.

Comment: it is in background, sorry i forgot to add that.

Comment: Please share the msg body, that you are sending from firebase dashboard or api

Comment: "alert" this is the message bosy i am sending from my api