# How to stop receiving notifications when app is killed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to don't receive **notifications** when my app is killed but I have not found any code that does.

I can receive notifications in **foreground** and **background** but they still arrive when I kill the app.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " +  remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
            }
            catch (Exception e){           
            }
        }

        //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
        //You can change as per the requirement.
      try {
    //message will contain the Push Message
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
    //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
    String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    String titulo = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String sidusuario = remoteMessage.getData().get("sidusuario");
    String idnotificacionusuario = remoteMessage.getData().get("idnotificacionusuario");

    sendNotification(message, imageUri,titulo);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();       
    }

}
```

This is my **sendNotification method**

```
void sendNotification(String messageBody, String icon, String titulo)
{

    String channelId = "General";
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromURL(icon))
                    .setContentTitle(titulo)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_blanco_chapur)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(getID(), notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

{
       "to": "token",
           "notification": {
            "title": "title",
            "body": "****body****.",
            "mutable_content": true
        },

```
    "data": {
        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/Coiled_Galaxy.jpg",
        "title": "title",
        "body": "****body****."
    }


}
```

Comment: _Data_ payload will be worked. You need to set priority _high_ for notification.

Comment: What sort of payload are you sending? Is it a data-only payload? Can you post the firebase payload you are trying to send too?

Comment: i  want the notifications to be displayed when the app is in foreground or background. But does not want the notification to be displayed if the app was killed.

Comment: {
 
"to": "token",

    "notification": {
        "title": "title",
        "body": "****body****.",
        "mutable_content": true
    },
    
    "data": {
        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/Coiled_Galaxy.jpg",
        "title": "title",
        "body": "****body****."
    }
 
}

Answer (score 0):

It maybe duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58586867/fcm-shows-default-message-than-custom-message-when-app-is-not-running/58586958#58586958). *Important: if the app is in background or killed then to be received a notification the payload have to remove the `notification` property*

[image]

Comment: in the background and foreground if it should work, but when the app is killed it should not receive notifications

Comment: @AlexisOsorio Have you tested it. If not, you should try. When the app is in background it doesn't mean the app was killed. It takes short time to be killed by OS

Comment: @AndroidDev. OP is saying that he wants the notifications to be displayed when the app is in foreground or background. But does not want the notification to be displayed if the app was killed.

Comment: Yes, i  want the notifications to be displayed when the app is in foreground or background. But does not want the notification to be displayed if the app was killed.

Comment: @AlexisOsorio, I suggest that you are able to create a new class that extents from `Application` class(if you don't have one). In the `onCreate()` method, you call `registerReceiver` method for registering a receiver. And then, in the `onMessageReceived` method of the `FirebaseService` you send a broadcast receiver when you receiving a notification. I hope it helps.