# Message doesn't appear when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM in my app and in `onmessagerecieve()` function i perform some functionality. I implement both methods if remote message is either notification or data message. 
There are four cases in my app

- Receive notification message when app is in foreground (it works fine what i want)
- Receive data message when app is in foreground (it works fine what i want)
- Receive notification message when app is in background (it works fine what i want)
- Receive data message when app is in background (**it is creating problem for me**)

The problem is when I receive data messages and app is background... Nothing happens neither any notification nor original functionality performed.
I want to perform the same functionality when I receive data message when app is in foreground

```
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("FCM type is Notification");
            parseNotificationMessage(remoteMessage);

        } else {
            System.out.println("FCM type is Data");
            parseDataMessage(remoteMessage);
        }

    }

    private void parseNotificationMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String notification_title =remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();

        String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_title);
        System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_message);
        String first_letter = "";
        String title = "";
        try {
            first_letter = notification_title.substring(0, 1);
            title = notification_title.substring(1);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }

        if (first_letter.equals("@")&& title.equals("NewOrder")) {
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_title);
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_message);

            Intent intent = new Intent("JSON_DATA");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Notification_JSON",notification_message );
            bundle.putString("Signal","NewOrder");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);


        }
        else if (first_letter.equals("@")&& title.equals("CancelOrder")) {
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_title);
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_message);

            Intent intent = new Intent("JSON_DATA");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Notification_JSON",notification_message );
            bundle.putString("Signal","CancelOrder");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

        else {

            generateNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_title);
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_message);
        }
    }

    private void parseDataMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String notification_title =remoteMessage.getData().get("title");

        String notification_message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

        System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_title);
        System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_message);
        String first_letter = "";
        String title = "";
        try {
            first_letter = notification_title.substring(0, 1);
            title = notification_title.substring(1);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }

        if (first_letter.equals("@")&& title.equals("NewOrder")) {
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_title);
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_message);

            Intent intent = new Intent("JSON_DATA");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Notification_JSON",notification_message );
            bundle.putString("Signal","NewOrder");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);


        }
        else if (first_letter.equals("@")&& title.equals("CancelOrder")) {
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_title);
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_message);

            Intent intent = new Intent("JSON_DATA");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Notification_JSON",notification_message );
            bundle.putString("Signal","CancelOrder");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

        else {

            generateNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"), remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_title);
            System.out.println("1234567::   "+notification_message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should have look on my old answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58586867/fcm-shows-default-message-than-custom-message-when-app-is-not-running/58586958#58586958

Comment: @JohnLe actually to run onmessagerecieve() when message type is data and app is in background.. Is it posssible?

Comment: in which version of the android device creates a problem (below orio or from orio and above orio)

Comment: Below oreo currently I m testing on Marshmallow

Comment: `DataMessage` push will be received either app background/foreground instead `NotificationMessage` push

Comment: use notification channal to show your notification

Comment: @SanaJaved, you're right. If you want to the `onMessageReceive()` will be call when app is in background and foreground,  the notification only contents the `data`(remove the `notification`)

Comment: ok i have detected when app is in background and i receive on data message ... it runs on messagerecieved() but functionality isn't performing

Comment: look in the function  private void parseNotificationMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)  ... i think intent is not working

Answer (score 0):

below marshmallow, you have to use ***NotificationCompat.Builder*** to show you message and you have to use ***NotificationChannal*** to above or equal to marshmallow

```
     NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "notify_001");
    Intent ii = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), RootActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, ii, 0);

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigText.bigText(verseurl);
    bigText.setBigContentTitle("Title");
    bigText.setSummaryText("Text in detail");

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Your Title");
    mBuilder.setContentText("Your text");
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notify_001",
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

To make firebase library to call your **onMessageReceived()** in the following cases

**App in foreground**

**App in background**

**App has been killed**

you must not put JSON key 'notification' in your request to firebase API but instead use 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is in background if you send both notification and data message you won't receive any notification message or data message inside `onMessageReceived()` . The notification message will be delivered into the system tray as a notification and data message will be sent to the extras of the activity's intent which you launch when the notification is clicked. What you can do is send only data message with notification title and description so that you can show them as a notification or do whatever you want. On the other hand you can handle your data message when notification is clicked from extras of the intent like this :

Get "data" info from notification in the onCreate of ".MainActivity":

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //get notification data info
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
       //Handle data
    }
}
```